# canvasjs in decimal format with suffix is not working properly

Tags: canvasjs

I use canvasJS to make a line graph report, the issue now is it didn't show properly in tooltip using `yValueFormatString`.

my goal is to display the value:

```
{
    type:"stepLine",
    name: "title",
    showInLegend: true,
    connectNullData: true,
    yValueFormatString: "##.## %",
    dataPoints: [     
       { x: new Date(2019, 1, 20), y: 12.78 },
          { x: new Date(2019, 1, 19), y: 12.79 },
          { x: new Date(2019, 1, 18), y: 12.80 },
       ]
}
```

in tooltip, it shows

```
1278 %
1279 %
1280 %
```

I think there's something wrong with it, I wanted to display like:

```
12.78 %
12.79 %
12.80 %
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/valueformatstring/), "%" Multiplies a number by 100 i.e. `12.78("##.## %") => 1278%`. Instead setting `yValueFormatString to "##.#0 '%'"` should work fine in this case.

Here is an example:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  data: [{
    type:"stepLine",
    name: "title",
    showInLegend: true,
    connectNullData: true,
    yValueFormatString: "##.#0 '%'",
    dataPoints: [     
      { x: new Date(2019, 1, 20), y: 12.78 },
      { x: new Date(2019, 1, 19), y: 12.79 },
      { x: new Date(2019, 1, 18), y: 12.80 },
    ]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 260px"></div>
```